# Permutations without replacement from a limited supply of identical objects of different types?

Tags: combinatorics

Exact Question:
Arrange a set of five DVDs for a display. The display is to be made up of one DVD from each of 5 categories. There are 4 Action, 4 Drama, 3 Comedy, 3 Documentary, and 2 Science Fiction DVDs from which to choose.
*No DVD can belong to more than one category*

How many different ways can someone choose DVDs for the display?

I think I simply am having trouble identifying what type of question this is (permutation, combination, etc).

Comment: Can you give an example of one or more of the types of "arrangements" you are trying to count?  Are all four of the action movies considered identical?  Or are each of the action movies different, like one copy of Jackie Chan's "Lots of fighting", a copy of Bruce Lee's "Even more fighting", Action heroes II: the need for more action, and Sharknado 2: the second one...

Comment: I think the question means to have each the DVDs be different.

Comment: This is a terrible question.  I would think that the different action movies are different and the order matters on the display.  In that case the categories don't matter at all and you just have $24$ movies to select $5$ in order.  Maybe all action movies are the same (some would say that) and the order matters but the specific movie does not.  Maybe you just care about how many movies of each type are among the five.  The question is not clear what we are trying to count, so there is no good answer.

Comment: I would think so too. My instructor thought it was clear that the movies were different. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Now that I can see the original question, I think you are supposed to pick one DVD from each category. So all that you need to do is to multiply $4\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 2$.

---

If the 16 DVDs are all distinguishable, then the answer is obviously ${16\choose 5}\cdot 5! = 16!/11!$.

You pick $5$ of the CDs, then arrange them in one of $5!$ ways.

---

If the DVDs in each category are the same, and order matters, then the problem can be solved using **exponential generating functions**.

For the action or drama category, you can pick between 0 and 4 identical DVDs:

$$1+x+\tfrac1{2!}x^2+\tfrac1{3!}x^3+\tfrac1{4!}x^4$$

For the comedy or documentary category, you can pick between 0 and 3 identical DVDs:

$$1+x+\tfrac1{2!}x^2+\tfrac1{3!}x^3$$

And for sci-fi, you can pick between 0 and 2 identical DVDs:

$$1+x+\tfrac1{2!}x^2$$

Multiplying all these five expressions together, you get:

$$(1+x+\tfrac1{2!}x^2+\tfrac1{3!}x^3+\tfrac1{4!}x^4)^2(1+x+\tfrac1{2!}x^2+\tfrac1{3!}x^3)^2(1+x+\tfrac1{2!}x^2)$$

If you expand with a computer, you will find that the coefficient of $x^5$ is $\frac{145}6$. Multiplying this by $5!$, you get the answer $2900$.

This solution assumes that the final order matters. If you are just *choosing* the DVDs, then the procedure is the same, but the first expression should be $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$, etc, and you don't need to multiply by $5!$ at the end.

Comment: I count $24$ DVDs